# Mutate an empty data frame's column safely

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have an empty data frame. I try to assign some value to a column of this data frame. Since the data frame is empty, I expect to obtain an empty data frame in return as follows:

```
df = data_frame(a = integer())
df %>%
  mutate(a = 1)
# A tibble: 0 × 1
# ... with 1 variables: a <dbl>
```

The problem occurs when assigned value is a vector. Then I get the following error:

```
df %>%
  mutate(a = 1:2)
# Error: wrong result size (2), expected 0 or 1
```

When I try to assign a value using `$` operator, then even assigning a single value produces error:

```
df$a = 1
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "a", value = 1) :
# replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

What is the correct and safe way to try to mutate an empty data frame's column?

**Update:**

Note that, I expect to get empty data frame back. I don't want to add new rows to the data frame.

I expect to get empty data frame back because mutate and `$` operators don't change number of rows normally. I don't want to violate their normal behavior.

I am looking for a concise solution. It is possible to solve this problem wrapping the code into a `tryCatch` or `if` expression. But they will clutter the actual code. I wonder if there is any better way.

Comment: Try `df %>% bind_rows(., data_frame(a=1))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I expect to get empty data frame back. I don't want to add new rows to the data frame.

Comment: Not sure what it is exactly that you want, but you could wrap that certain step into `df %>% tryCatch(. %>% mutate(a = 1:2), error = return(df)) %>% etc.`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, for the suggestion. I am looking for a safe solution that is as concise as possible. I can use `tryCatch` or `if` but they clutter the code. I wonder if there is a solution that won't clutter the actual code.

Comment: `mutate` returns an error, I don't know how are you expecting handle errors without a bit of cluttering the code. I think that `tryCatch` line isn't so bad.

Comment: Maybe there might be a way to make `mutate` not to produce an error.

Comment: `tryCatch` is the safe version. It's essentially what the tidyverse suggests - e.g. `?purrr::safely`. So... `safe_mutate <- function(.data, ...) { tryCatch( mutate(.data, ...), error = function(e) { warning(e); return(.data)}) }; data_frame(a = integer()) %>% safe_mutate(a = 1:2)`.

Comment: FWIW, I suppose the fact that the `mutate(a = 1)` scenario works at all is probably more of a by-product of dplyr logic and not necessarily intended.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
df <- data_frame(a = integer())
df %>%
   mutate(a = (1:10)[seq_len(nrow(df))])
```

OR

```
df$a <- (1:10)[seq_len(nrow(df))]
```

Basically, the column will get populated if `df` has any rows in it; if not then empty dataframe is returned. Replace `(1:10)` with your desired vector.